# What's the best material for a durable muffin pan

Tags: baking, equipment, muffins

I make two or three dozen muffins a day for various customers. I don't like to use disposable cups, so I grease the pan each time. No matter what I do, after a certain time, my muffin pans end up giving a subtle metal taste to my muffins.

I was wondering what would be the most appropriate material for a muffin mold to avoid this situation. I'd be ready to pay the price for a pan that would last significantly longer... Bug which one should I choose?

Comment: Are you sure that it is the pans giving the metal taste? I have had problems with old and/or caked by humidity baking powder. While yours is probably fresh, if the recipe has big amounts of it, long-acting bp will give a slight aluminium taste, more noticeable after the muffin has cooled. What material are your pans? Almost no pan metal should give off a taste, except for untreated aluminium. Anodized/coated aluminium, nonreactive metals and seasoned iron/carbon steel will not change the taste.

Comment: Try boiling water in the molds with a little baking soda and tasting it. It won't fix anything but you'll be able to tell whether or not the pan is really to blame (it will have a metallic taste).

Answer (score 3):

First, I concur with @rumtscho that the pans may not be the culprit and second, I do not make muffins in anywhere near the quantities you report, but I have had great luck with [silicon muffin trays](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0032AM7NS). They clean well and release the muffins nicely.